# Two forms from one input

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm wondering how I can make this work, unfortunately my code doesn't work. I want my form to have two buttons; one goes to the other PHP file, and the other goes to another PHP file.

The first button, *SUBMIT*, is working fine. But the second button, *SEE RANK*, is not working, nothing happens after clicking it

```
 <section class="small-section bg-gray-lighter" id="start">
                    <div class="container relative">

                        <!-- FORMS -->
                        <form id="format" class="form align-center" action="Algorithms/article.php" method = "GET">  
                           <form id="rank" class="form align-center" action="Algorithms/Main2.php"  method = "GET">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8 align-center col-md-offset-2">

                                    <div class="newsletter-label font-alt">
                                        Type the description of your case below
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mb-20">

                                        <!-- INPUT TEXT FIELD -->
                                        <input placeholder="Start typing here" name = "caseInput" class="newsletter-field form-control input-md round mb-xs-12"  type="text"  required/>

                              </form>
                           </form>
                                       <!-- BUTTONS -->
                                        <button form="format" type="submit" class="btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round mb-xs-10">
                                            Submit
                                        </button> 
                                        <button form="rank" type="submit" class="btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round mb-xs-10">
                                            See rank
                                        </button> 

                                        <!-- END OF BUTTONS -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-tip">
                                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Ex. "The father killed her daughter."
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="subscribe-result"></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @bkausbk, the first button is working fine. but the other button "see rank" is not clickable.

Comment: Please don't call form inside the form. Using jQuery you can change the action of the form then it will be work for both.

Comment: Your HTML is a mess. Start by cleaning that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it doesn't make sense to use `<form>` inside `<form>`. There are couple of ways to do this:

**Method 1**

Use 2 forms instead.

```
<form method="post" action="php_file_1.php" id="form1">
    <!-- Your further HTML Code Goes Here...   -->
</form>
<form method="post" action="php_file_2.php" id="form2">
    <!-- Your further HTML Code Goes Here...   -->
</form>
```

**Method 2**

Use a single PHP file. But perform different function on each button click.

```
<form method="post" action="functions.php" id="form">
    <!-- Your further HTML Code Goes Here...   -->
    <input type="submit" name="action_1" id="button1">
    <input type="submit" name="action_2" id="button2">
</form>
```

Then in your functions.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['action_1'])){
    action1(); // Your Function Name...
}
elseif(isset($_POST['action_2'])){
    action2(); // Your second function
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a form inside a form.  (This is why your second buton does not work)

So, your solution will be to have 2 'submit' elements with different names in your form.  Then, on form submission, detect and process accordingly depending on which button was pressed.

```
 <!-- BUTTONS -->
 <input type="submit" name='submitAction1' class="btn..." value='Submit'>
 <input type="submit" name='submitAction2' class="btn..." value='See rank'>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['submitAction1'])){

    // process form 1

} elseif (isset($_POST['submitAction2'])){

    // process form 2

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [XHTML™ 1.0 The Extensible HyperText Markup Language (Second Edition) - B. Element Prohibitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

> `form` must not contain other `form` elements

---

Implementation example with a javascript function which changes the form's action:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <script>
            function mySubmit(wtf) {
              if ('article' == wtf ) {
                  document.forms['myForm'].action = 'Algorithms/article.php';
              } else if ('Main2' == wtf ) {
                  document.forms['myForm'].action = 'Algorithms/Main2.php';
              } else
                  return false;

              document.forms['myForm'].submit();
            }
        </script>

        <form name="myForm">
            <input type ="button" value="submit article" class="btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round mb-xs-10" onClick="mySubmit('article')">
            <input type ="button" value="submit Main2" class="btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round mb-xs-10" onClick="mySubmit('Main2')">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```